# How to emulate a xbox 360 controller in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, linux, emulation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, joystick

I am a windows 10 user and using wsl to run ubuntu 16.04 to use ROS without a virtual machine.Now I need to use a jotstick to control a robot simulation in gazebo but the problem is wsl doesn't support usb joysticks yet. I have tried USBIP and it doesn't work without wsl2.

So I used [inputs](https://pypi.org/project/inputs/#:%7E:text=About,and%20your%20granddad%27s%20Python%202.7.) library to get data from joystick and using socket to "transmit" and  then "receive" and print the data in a script running in the wsl terminal. I am sending the data whenever a joystick event occurs.I am planning to use the received data to emulate a xbox 360 controller.

I have looked into the [evdev](https://pypi.org/project/evdev) library but failed to find documentation on how to emulate xbox 360 controller. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know anything about Gazebo, but is there any way to get it to accept input not from a joystick? That's probably easier.

Comment: My problem is not with gazebo,I need to emulate a joystick from a script

Comment: If WSL does not support USB Joysticks or [`uinput`](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3997), then it sounds like your options are (1) don't use WSL (WSL2 might work?) or (2) find a workaround for needing a joystick.

Comment: have you looked into the [joy package](http://wiki.ros.org/joy) of ROS? It already supports xbox 360 controllers and with a ROS package it will be much easier to control the robot in Gazebo

Comment: The problem is I am running ROS on a "Virtual Machine" which can't detect input devices thus the directory /dev/input/ doesn't exist - @rfn123